# How can I make a grid with more than 12 columns?

Tags: zurb-foundation

How can I make a grid with more than 12 columns? I'd like to make a grid to represent 24 hours in a day in half hour increments (total of 48 columns).

```
<div class="row display">
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
    <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you use Sass Version of zurb-foundation? Why don't use variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize Foundation on [this subpage](http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php#customizeFoundation) of Zurb, and you can set 48 columns for yourself. Then you can use large classes from `.large-1` to `.large-48`, and small classes from `.small-1` to `.small-48`.

Comment: This page doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use a `nested Grid`.

First you divide your `row` into 2 `columns`. Than you place your 12 hours into each section:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">1</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">2</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">3</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">4</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">5</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">6</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">7</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">8</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">9</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">10</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">11</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">12</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">13</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">14</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">15</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">16</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">17</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">18</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">19</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">20</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">21</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">22</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">23</div>
            <div class="small-2 large-1 columns">24</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for something similar, finally figured out how to do this with foundation's mixins.

In another scss file you can create your custom class as follows.  This only implements the coding for the "large-x" sub class for this parent class.  I reset the total-columns variable to 12 just in case.

```
@import "foundation/components/grid"

.customClassName {
  $total-columns:24;
  @include grid-row();
  @include grid-html-classes($size:large);
  $total-columns:12;
}
```

This gives me a 24 column grid that I can place anywhere without overwriting the defaults for foundation in the project.

Answer (score 0):

There a most likely multiple solutions to this. I tried the solution from Jay, and it does not work - not sure why? So I discovered another solution - there's a function in Foundation that can be used.

Let's assume that you're outputting the alphabet A-Z as a list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="grid-26">A</li>
    ...
    <li class="grid-26">Z</li>
</ul>
```

In your SCSS, create your class and call the grid-calc function:

```
.grid-26 {
    width: grid-calc(1, 26);
}
```

This will return a width which equals 1/26 or 3.84615%

Dress up the SCSS so that each li floats and the text is centered:

```
.grid-26 {
    width: grid-calc(1, 26);
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```